# How to call script via ajax crossdomain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can you help me to make request via ajax crossdomain?

what i have:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login.php",
        data: {
        email: document.loginform.email.value,
        password: document.loginform.password.value,
        }
      }).done(function(msg){});
```

i'm calling it FROM https://m.domain.com/login.php - it works. But, i want to call same script login.php which is on domain.com.

As you could guess i'm working on mobile version of website. i want make post requests from m.domain.com to scripts that is situated on domain.com

Using absolute address like:
 `url: "https://domain.com/login.php",` - no success..

i also tried make url like 
`"/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/"` for ajax request.. still no result..

Comment: you have to enable CORS (cross origin resource sharing ). http://stackoverflow.com/a/7605119/6236436

Comment: AWAYSOME!! Thx allot !!! It helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow CORS for https://m.domain.com on https://domain.com/login.php.

[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)

Comment: So can you help me what i should do? 

add this on domain.com/login.php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");